# C++ recursive code to iterative

Tags: c++, recursion

Hi guys so I have this code that I need for a project in university.The code I have is recursive and it is taking a lot of time to load.I tried converting it to iterative but I can't seem to do it in order as the output is different.Could you please help me converting it?Thank you.

```
void getBrewCount(int n, int i, int j){
 if( i ==n && j == n){ //reach the (n,n) point
  count++;
 }else if( i > n || j > n){//wrong way
     return;
 }else {
    if(i==8 && j==5){
        j++;
    }
    if(i==11 && j==5){
        j+=2;
    }
    if(i==15 && j>=14){
        i+=2;
    }
    if(i==21 && j>=22){
        i++;
    }
     getBrewCount(n, i +1, j );
     getBrewCount(n, i , j +1);
 }
```

Comment: You may use a `std::stack` and a small struct that contains the 3 parameter values.

Comment: @Alexandru Madalin  For starters could you say what the function does?

Comment: When you say, it take a lot of time, what would be number you use when calling the function and what would be the result in that case? Having an idea would be helpful as if n is between 0 and 25, we might not give the same answer as if it would be between 1 and 10 millions for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recursion you have an ending condition. When this condition is met, recursion ends and you "bubble up" from recursion. When you want to do the same iteratively, ending condition of recursion should be condition of your loop. Your recursion ends after it goes out of range. You can write while() loop which will loop until it reaches out of range, therefore while (i < n && j < n) { }. My while loop increments count and breaks itself right when range is achieved. However I do not know what is the real functionality of your function, so you might want to change it a little.

```
void getBrewCount(int n, int i, int j) {
   while (i < n && j < n) {
      // my ending condition
      if (i == n && j == n) {
        ++count;
        break;
      }

      /* code that updates i, j e.g.
      if (i == 10)
         ++j;
      */
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! It worked I tried something like that too but forgot about the break

Comment: The first `if` statement will never be triggered.

Comment: well it was just an example how it could be handled, point is he himself should find a condition when while { } will end.

Comment: Yes I got the idea I will finish it myself :)

Comment: This cannot works as neither `i` nor `j` would be incremented if you start with `5, 0, 0` for example as none of the condition inside the lopp are verified so it would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Phil1970 as I said earlier this is not supposed to be correct implementation. This is just an example how you can make itaration out of recursion

Comment: **But can it be used to make the correct implementation?** In the original code, it would try all possibilities that reach a given number but with a single loop, you could only reach one possibility. If there would be a single recursive call at the end of the function, then it would have been easy to figure out missing code (that is `i++` if the first line only is kept).

Comment: there, made it more theoretical. Hope it made you happier

Comment: The problem is not what you have wrote but more the missing parts... As far as I understand, the code would essentially count the number of path between initial pair (`i` and `j` in top level call) and the final position where `i` and `j` are equal to `n`.

Comment: yea i see, but that wasn't point of my answer. I didn't want to write a functional code for him. I wanted to show him possible way how to do it and the approach he could take for finishing his task.